# Do not minify one file in a bundle

Tags: minify, bundling-and-minification, web-optimization

I have several files that I want to include in a bundle using Web Optimizations but one of the files is currently breaking after minification. Is there a way to include that file in the bundle un-minified while still having all the other files be minified?

Something to the effect of this:

bundleCollection.Add( new ScriptBundle( "Name" ).Include( fileArray ) ).IncludeUnMinified( fileArray2 );

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't work when it is minified? Or it is breaking minification and not getting minified? You can try just changing the name to `something.min.js` because I don't think it will try to minify files that are named like that.